# Why don't electrons take the shorter path in coils?

Tags: current, electromagnetism, coil, electricity

Below is a copper coil, presumably forming an electromagnet. From my understanding the electrons travel around the coil to produce a magnetic field. But why don't the electrons jump the wires and take the shortest path?

Below I tried to draw the path that would make sense (for me) for the electrons to take:

[image]

Comment: Can you also post original image? Isn't the coil insulated?

Comment: The wire is coated with an insulating layer.

Comment: Are such coils always insulated? Even those really small wires forming a coil?

Comment: @Ruan Especially that so-called "magnet wire".

Comment: @Ruan I'd say they're always insulated because when we put a coil in a system we want the electricity to have to flow through it rather than taking a shortcut.  I only hesitate with "always" because there may be some super-exotic situation where you wanted the short.  Perhaps there's a time where you want a solid ring of copper connected to something, but due to some mechanical properties you want to make it out of wire rather than one solid chunk.  I can't think of any cases of that happening, but electrical engineers are a clever bunch!

Comment: @Ruan coils *can* be made from bare wire, but they have to have loose turns (not touching), and can't handle high voltages. There aren't many commercial situations where this is useful, but you might see it in a hobby project.

Comment: Huh, my magnet wire growing up had a red tint to it.

Comment: Distance-*shimistance*.... [Path of least resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_of_least_resistance)

Comment: If I'm correct, the point is that these are not elections which travel (they do, of course, but they are not the main thing that is happening) - it's the field that propagates through conductor material which makes the difference - if wire is not insulated and is stretched so that layers are farther away, the propagation still happens through the wire more likely than through the air (unless potential gradient is high enough).

Comment: @Mazura that's not really how it works. Put one resistor \$R_1\$ and one \$R_2 = 2\cdot R_1\$ in parallel, and _not_ all of the current will go through \$R_1\$ but only \$\tfrac23\$ of it. Moreover, if the lower-resistance one goes around a transformer core, that will actually induce a potentially much higher voltage than the resistive one, so even if the winding has a much lower resistance than the air gap between the windings, you may still get arcing between them.

Comment: I've wondered about this since high-school physics; it never made any sense and they never mentioned the insulation. Great question.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This type of wire, used for making coils, is commonly called "magnet wire". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_wire

It looks like it's bare copper, but it's actually coated with a very thin layer of transparent insulation. Otherwise, you're absolutely right -- if the wire were really bare, the coil wouldn't work because the current could cut straight across from one lead to the other.

Comment: That makes sense, for some reason i couldn't find an answer online, thanks

Comment: The windings are layered carefully, particularly on high voltage devices, so that adjacent layers do not have large potential differences. This reduces the stress on the insulation layers so it doesn't matter if they are thin or suffer damage.

Comment: And if you've ever made the mistake of thinking this is just bare wire, you find very rapidly that you can't solder to it because the insulation burns and then gets in your way, preventing adhesion.  When soldering such wire, one typically has to chemically strip the end so that it isn't insulated first.

Comment: And accidental damage to the insulation (or cracking caused by heat or corrosive environments or excessive inductive motion of the coil or ....) causes shorts in which the current does short-cut along the way which makes the magnet less effective.

Comment: @CortAmmon, I've scraped off the insulation on these ends before. It's a pain/annoying, so taking it off chemically makes sense if you're doing it more than twice.

Comment: @CortAmmon Depending on the thickness one can strip the insulation off the end by just dipping it in molten solder (on the tip of your soldering iron) for a few seconds. You'll see it smoking which is the lacquer burning off

Comment: Or you can burn the insulation off with fire. I once worked in a place where the assemblers had little alcohol burners for stripping magnet wire.

Comment: I have used a combination of butane cigarette lighter, knife blade, and abrasive paper.

Comment: Pulling the end a few times through a folded piece of emery paper works also.  The insulation tends to pull away with the friction, so you end up removing surprisingly little copper--not enough to matter matter electrically or mechanically, at least at my amateur level.  Don't do this on spacecraft, life support systems, or if your boss is looking.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes they do take the shortest path, when they are not supposed to. As others have said, the wires are normally insulated. However, if a current flowing in the magnet is suddenly interrupted by (say) an open circuit the voltage will rise until those electrons "get out" - either by sparking across an air gap or breaking through the insulation.

Comment: Think about the water in your pipes.   The water flows in the pipes as long as the pressure is not to great.  But at sufficiently high pressure, the water gets out and eventually flows to the lowest point available.  This could happen if a very high voltage is suddenly applied to your inductor.  Of course the inductor can fail in other ways: excessive current for too long will cause heating that destroys the insulation and you will have a smoking problem...